# Making a master checklist sheet in excel that filters entries

Tags: microsoft-excel

The title probably doesn't do a good job explaining what im trying to do, so i will do my best here. I am attempting to make a master checklist in excel. This checklist will have a list of employee names followed by sections for other lists such as w-4 forms, 1-9 forms, ect. When an employee fills out a form such as a w-4, i want to check off on this master next to their name that i have their w-4 form completed. Where it becomes complicated is, i want an easy way for excel to be able to generate a list of names for say employees that don't have an i-9 form on record without me manually searching through each name.

If i need to explain anything a little better, let me know. Thank you for any input!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Just filtering a simple grid will do what you want. Highlight your data, and click on "Filter". If you want to find all employees who are missing Form2, then you'll filter that column to show only blanks.

```
        Form1    Form2   Form3
Name1     x                x
Name2              x       x
Name3     x                x
```